# Unable to resize the image when using url() as the content's value

Tags: html, css, url

I'm trying to change the dimensions of the inserted image, but without success. Any ideas?

```css
.cricket:before {
  content: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B3VH- vDrMwo/maxresdefault.jpg");
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <p> I love earth </p>
</div>
<div class="cricket">
  <p> I love cricket </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:before` selector has to have a `display` property set to another value (e.g. `block`) in order to take the `width` and `height` into account.

Also: the `content` property should contain text, not an image. If you want to display an image you can use `background-image`. Like this:

```
.cricket:before{
   content: '';
   display: block;
   background-image:url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B3VH-vDrMwo/maxresdefault.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2c6qhu5e/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting what `content` does. You need to set an empty content, display the element as a block-level item and use `background`:

```css
.cricket:before{
   background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B3VH-vDrMwo/maxresdefault.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;   
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="earth">
  <p> I love earth </p>
</div>

<div class="cricket">
  <p> I love cricket </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

look in to this.....

http://jsfiddle.net/2c6qhu5e/14/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="earth">
<p> I love earth </p>
</div>

<div class="cricket">
<p> I love cricket </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>

    .cricket:before{
  position: absolute;
   top:0;
    left:0;
    content: " ";
    background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B3VH-vDrMwo/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
}
```